# Full HTTP URL for IIS URL Rewrite module

Tags: http, iis, url-rewrite-module

Is any possibility to match whole url in IIS URL Rewrite module?
I need to write the next condition:

```
<add input="{FULL_URL}" negate="true" pattern="^https:\/\/www\..+[^/]$" />
```

I want to ignore all urls that starts with `https://www` and ended with `/`.
Does `{FULL_URL}` or something else exist?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS rewrite exists variable `{CACHE_URL}` which should be suitable for you.

This variable contains full URL including query string. Ex: `http://localhost:8080/Home/About?id=5`

You can find full list of variables with explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx